# Bizarre admin menu problem after upgrading craft to latest version

Tags: routes, admin, upgrades

Hi not sure if anyone has come across this issue before? I upgraded craft to the latest version on my test site. I have a few custom plugins that I have created on this site. The front-end seems to be working Ok. However I have a strange thing happening in the admin. The settings menu item is re-directing to one of my plugins?? So I can't access the settings at all. The menu link is showing as admin/settings and there are no routes set in either the routes.php config file or anything in the .htaccess.

Anyone any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I've had this with the Dukt Analytics plugin, hitting Settings took me straight to the Analytics settings and nothing else.
Not particularly helpful in this instance but an upgrade to the plugin sorted the problem.